# Looking for an algorithm that gives me all partitions of a list given a block size as input

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I am working on a problem that requires me to find all possible combinations of the alphabet given the amount of divisional-blocks as an input.

Here is what I mean:

- Take the following array as an input alphabet = `[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I]`
- Now an arbitrary block size is given, for example 4
- What are all the possible combinations of the input array given the amount of blocks?
- e.g. :

  - `[ [A,B], [C,D], [E,F], [G,H,I] ]`
  - `[ [A,B], [C,D], [E,F,G], [H,I] ]`
  - `[ [A,B], [C,D], [E,F,G,H], [I] ]`
  - `[ [A,B], [C,D,E], [F,G,H], [I] ]`
  - `[ [A,B], [C,D,E,F], [G,H], [I] ]`
  - ...
  - `[ [A,B,C,D], [E,F,G], [H], [I] ]`
  - `[ [A,B,C,D,E], [F,G], [H], [I] ]`
  - `[ [A,B,C,D,E,F], [G], [H], [I] ]`
  - etc.

I do not need all the possible permutations, e.g. `[ [C,A], [B,D], [F,E], [G,H,I] ]` **is not needed**, I just need the ones that keep the lexicographical order of the alphabet. I am sure there is an algorithm out there for this - would be awesome if someone could point me to it.

Comment: Draw arrows at the split between each block. Number the arrows based on the preceding element (in all of your examples, the first arrow would be numbered "1"). For 4 blocks, you want all 3-element permutations taken from the set `[0, n - 1)`

Comment: If the array is of size `n` and no. of blocks `b`, then `n-1`C`b` is what you are looking for. It can be done with a simple recursive exhaustive search.

Answer (score 1):

You split `[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I]` at each comma. Each comma is can be seen as a position in the range of 1 to 8. Once you have chosen the first position, it cannot be chosen a second time.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::vector<std::uint32_t> positions{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    std::vector<std::string> positionStrings;
    for(int i = 0; i < positions.size() - 2; ++i)
    {
       std::uint32_t firstPosition = positions[i];
       for(int j = i + 1; j < positions.size() - 1; ++j)
       {
          std::uint32_t secondPosition = positions[j];
          for(int k = j + 1; k < positions.size(); ++k)
          {
             std::uint32_t thirdPosition = positions[k];
             positionStrings.push_back(std::to_string(firstPosition) + "," + std::to_string(secondPosition) + "," + std::to_string(thirdPosition));
          }
       }
    }
    // You can split up the strings again by token "," and convert to numbers if needed. But this is a detail, not the algorithm which you asked for.
    for(auto string : positionStrings)
    {
        std::cout << string << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that there are 8 commas (9 letters) in the original set...

Comment: Did you try to compile that code ?

Comment: Looks good! :-)

Comment: @JanHackenberg Thanks for your answer, this is not exactly what I was after. Your code provides me with all the possible configurations (of size 3) for the positions vector `positions{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}`, but what I need is an algorithm that outputs something along these lines: `[ [1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8] ]` (based on a 3 block input) which would give me all possible partitions for the vector without changing the order.

Comment: @JackGold But this is what gives you your answer. You have a vector of 9 chars, which you want to split by 3 splits into 4 segments. My algorithm gives the 3 split positions which you look for, e.g. [1,3,5] translates to split after first, third and fifths char, i.e. [a],[b,c],[d,e],[f,g,h,i]

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I have one concern though, your code would work for only 4 segments (i.e. 3 splits) but won't allow any arbitrary number of splits, for example if I wanted to use your code to work for 8 splits it wouldn't work, correct me if I am wrong?